# Chronicle Queue: Is recordHistory() not available anymore?

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue, chronicle-wire

I'd like to benchmark the queue performance using the method demonstrated in [github README](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue#detailed-tracing-of-timings).

However, when I tried on the latest version (chronicle-queue: 5.23ea5, chronicle-wire: 2.23ea5), `recordHistory(bool recordHistory)` doesn't seem to be available, I doubled checked [javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/net.openhft/chronicle-wire/latest/net/openhft/chronicle/wire/VanillaMethodWriterBuilder.html).

`MethodWriterBuilder` seemed to have been replaced by `VanillaMethodWriterBuilder`, which does not have `recordHistory(bool recordHistory)` method.

Does this library still provide a way of tracing messages and adding timestamps as they move through the system?

I would appreciate any pointers. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes recordHistory(bool) has been removed. It was only useful if sourceId was set so now setting sourceId (on the queue) will turn on recordHistory automatically.

We are updating the CQ documentation to reflect this.